# MySQL stored procedure with a cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

From the table "redis-state" I want to get data with cursor in table and written this procedure, but I get an error

> declare not founds 1064 error code

at line 10.

Purpose is to print the table all rows. One print for each entry in table.

[image: table]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE redisatestatedata()
    BEGIN 
     DECLARE macaddress varchar(50);
     DECLARE redisstate varchar(50);
     DECLARE atehistorystate varchar(50);
     DECLARE data_list varchar(50000);
     DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

     DECLARE data_cursor CURSOR FOR  
      SELECT macaddress,redisstate,atehistorystate 
      FROM redis-atestate;

       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
         SET done = TRUE;
         open data_cursor;
     GET_DATA:loop FETCH data_cursor INTO 
          macaddress,redisstate,atehistorystate;

     IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
        leave get_data;
     ENDIF;

 SET data_list = concat("Difference in state ATE:",macaddress,": redis ",redisstate,": dbstate ",atehistorystate);

    SELECT data_list;
   loop get_data;
  CLOSE data_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry, I try to add code in question but no success, so pasted image

Comment: You can add your code by copy&paste, then select it and press `ctrl+k` (or the `{ }` symbol above the edit box). Also please add the exact (and complete) error message, including the part that quotes your code, as it will directly reveal the place of the error. This (error message and code as text) allows us to identify syntax problems like unquoted tablenames much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with this statement :

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
```

you are trying to assign a default value of false to data type INT?